# Kendo Grid Data Population Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid and i want to populate data on the grid. But before pupolation i have a condition.
Condition is if no records on grid data read(), then function `OnQuantityChange()` should be called.
For that I gave below code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        dataType: "json",
        data: { AssetHdId: AssetHdId },
        success: function (data) {
            var grdParameter = $("#DTList").data("kendoGrid");                
            var count;
            grdParameter.dataSource.read();
            count = grdParameter.dataSource.total();                     
            if (count == 0) {
                OnQuantityChange();
            }
        }
});
```

Function `OnQuantityChange();` contains code to set default data to kendo grid. Here i am getting data. Problem is data comes and removed automatically at the same time itself.

When i give just function only without the condition as below, its fine:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        dataType: "json",
        data: { AssetHdId: AssetHdId },
        success: function (data) {
            OnQuantityChange();                
        }
});
```

But here my requirement is data should be displayed with above conditions. 
When I add `alert()` on the first code, its working.

Comment: Do you want to know when no data is returned or when a aggregated calculation of the data returned is 0?

Comment: In case no data is returned, i need to set default value to the grid using `OnQuantityChange()`

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the length of the data returned?

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        dataType: "json",
        data: { AssetHdId: AssetHdId },
        success: function (data) {
            var grdParameter = $("#DTList").data("kendoGrid");                
            grdParameter.dataSource.read();                     
            if (data.length == 0) {
                OnQuantityChange();
            }
        }
});
```

Comment: But the `data.length` returns `undefined` value.

Comment: Is that indicative of no data or Is the length 0 when there is data?

Comment: Data is there. Eventhough `data.length` showing `undefined`

Comment: How about simply, if (data) { ... }